# Выбор изображения из загруженных файлов

Tags: php, laravel

Допустим для товара в админке нужно сделать возможность выбрать изображение, которое уже загружено.
Лучше чтобы была возможность сразу как загрузки нового изображения, так и возможность выбрать среди имеющихся изображений, чтобы прикрепить это изображение к товару.
Есть ли готовые модули для этого?
Можете посоветовать как это реализовать?

Comment: Выгружайте все фото с lazy loading (как на смартфоне - фото чтоб чекать можно было), ниже блока с фото прикрепить дропзону. Тут даже советовать нечего, в принципе

Comment: @InDevX, а если есть изображения распределены по папкам, как можно выгрузить изображения вместе с директориями, с сохранением структуры директорий?

Comment: т.е. чтобы отображались изображения вместе с директориями

Comment: Вы когда в базу записываете у вас есть поле url. Вы просто берёте их и разбиваете на папки (напр. первая часть url'a)

Comment: @InDevX, подскажите, если использовать дропзону, и нужно отображать изображения в модальном окне. Но изображений может быть много, как сделать, чтобы изображения подгружались по мере прокрутки модального окна? Пытался использовать blazy, в модальном окне такая подгрузка не работает